# QGIS: 2 layers using different CRS

Tags: gis, qgis, wgs84, epsg

I am trying to draw a map of tree protection orders locally. I have a .shp file which uses CRS: EPSG 4326. I can add this to a project and see something that looks sensible, but with no context of roads etc.
I then try to add a basemap layer of OpenStreetMap, which uses CRS: EPSG 3857.
I realise I need to change one or other of these so they are both using the same CRS, but am failing this step.

Please be gentle in your replies as I have very little QGIS experience and this is my first project. I am using QGIS v3.28.0

I have tried:

- converting OpenStreetMap to EPSG 4326. This gives a squished map, which is to be expected. But when I add the TPO.shp file as a vector layer, nothing shows up
- converting TPO.shp layer to EPSG 3857. This causes it to disappear and despite lots of panning and 'zoom to layer', I cannot find it. I can then add the OpenStreetMap layer which looks normal, but I can't see the TPO.shp layer.

Answer (score 0):

**You** don't need to change anything, that's what QGis is for (amongst other things). Provided it knows the projection of all the layers it can reproject them into the projection (CRS) of the **project** which is shown in the lower right hand corner of the tool bar.

So do nothing to the data and all will be well.

Comment: All isn't well though. If I add the TPO.shp first, then add the streetmap, all I can see is the TPO map without any context. So it's just the same as before I added the streetmap layer. If I add the streetmap layer first, then the TPO.shp, all I can see is the streetmap layer. This is a global map, so the scale would mean I can't see my local detail. I tried right-clicking the TPO layer and 'zoom to layer'. That takes me to somewhere in the sea, and still no TPO detail.

Comment: How are you adding the bademap?

Comment: I can see OpenStreetMap under XYZ Tiles in the browser section. I just drag and drop from there. I've been working on this project a long time, off and on, so have rather lost the plot of all the details - I started with zero knowledge of how to do it. But I believe I installed plugins - QuickOSM and QuickMapServices. At any rate, both these plugins are installed.

Comment: does your shapefile have a `.prj` file? if not then you can set the layer CRS to 4326

Comment: Yes, it has a .prj file

Comment: Then it should just line up, unless it's the wrong prj file